# How to add elements to set while traversing it?

Tags: c++, set

We have a set `S {1,10,100,1000,10000}`. Now we input an integer `x` (say `x` = `4`).

Now we have to add every element of set's product with `x` to the set itself. So finally

```
S={1,10,100,1000,10000,4,40,400,4000,40000}
```

[`S` is not limited to only 5 entries initially]

We have to visit only the initial elements in the set.
I tried an approach like:

```
for(auto i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)
{
    s.insert((*i)*x);
}
```

This doesnt give the desired result, as the size of set keeps increasing.

Another approach I tried was to store all the multiples `(*i)*x` in another temporary set/vector and to merge it with s later. 
But since the original dataset is huge, it worsens the time complexity.
Any optimizations ?

Comment: Add to a temporary set, then union the original and temporary set,

Comment: @RichardCritten I mentioned I already tried this approach. But the Time Complexity worsened as the original set is Huge.

Comment: The correct solution here requires understanding certain properties of `std::set` that makes it possible to implement this in `O(n)`, without using a temporary set.

Comment: *"it worsens the time complexity"* it is `O(n)` with merge (but `O(n log n)` with multiple insertion).

Comment: @Jarod42 Complexity requirement of `std::set::merge` is O(N log N). But the point that asymptotic complexity isn't worsened still stands.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `std::set` is ordered, and iterators are not invalidated by insertion, you can simply insert while iterating as long as you don't insert to the range that is still left to be iterated.

If we can assume all numbers to be positive, then we can iterate in reverse direction, because the result of multiplication is always going to be greater than the inputs:

```
for (auto it = S.rbegin(); it != S.rend(); ++it)
    S.insert(*it*x);
```

If `x` is negative and set contains only positive, then order of iteration doesn't matter. If the set may contain negative numbers, this becomes more challenging.

---

> But since the original dataset is huge, it worsens the time complexity.

Inserting N elements into `std::set` is O(N log N). Merging `std::set`s is O(N log N). The merge approach does not worsen asymptotic time complexity.

If you were to use an `std::unordered_set` though, the merge approach would be O(N) in average case. It's still O(N log N) in worst case however. I recommend using the merge approach with an unordered set.

Comment: I feel that the necessary property for this to work could be checked in `O(N)`, possibly using a custom comparison operator for `std::is_sorted`... Would make a good assertion.

Comment: You missed an obvious optimization, using an overloaded `insert()` that takes an additional hint iterator parameter. You already have it, right here. The new value will always be inserted after the current iterator position.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `The new value will always be inserted after the current iterator position.` Why? Consider for example: S={1,2} and x=4. I don't see the guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it's simplest to use a temporary set. With C++17, you can use `std::set::merge` with the temporary set casted to an rvalue:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::set<int> s2;

std::transform(s1.cbegin(), s1.cend(), std::inserter(s2, s2.end()),
      [](int orig){ return 4*orig; });

s1.merge(std::move(s2));
```

Otherwise, note that iterators into the set aren't invalidated while inserting. Take this together with the fact that the set is ordered and in case of the scenario you described (scaling an existing value is larger than the original value, but less or equal than the next existing one), you can do it in a loop like this:

```
for (auto it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); ++it)
   it = s.insert(*it*4).first;
```

For fewer restrictions, you can use this more verbose loop:

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator it1 = s.begin(), it2; it1 != s.end();
        it1 = std::next(it1) == it2 ? std::next(it1, 2) : it2)
   it2 = s.insert(*it1*4).first;
```

Comment: This is doable without a temporary object, using a certain approach that takes advantage of `std::set`'s properties.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Like this? It relies so heavily on the presumptions, not sure whether that's a good solution.

Comment: Your second loop will fail miserably if the original set contains {1,2,3}. It will add just 4, and terminate. The correct solution will work with any values in the set.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Then please share the correct solution instead of having us guess

Comment: @Justin I think this should do it. It's ugly though.

Comment: The correct solution has now been posted by someone: iterating in reverse order. It's pretty obvious that the number being multiplied is always positive, and by iterating in reverse order you'll never end up iterating over the new values in the set, this way. It's just that it was painfully obvious to me that this was some silly question from some other silly online quiz site, that nobody really cares about, and I just don't like to reward this kind of noise, with answers, and only encourage more of the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

std::set<int> & update( std::set<int> &s, int value )
{
    for ( auto it = rbegin( s ); it != rend( s ); ++it )
    {
        s.insert( *it * value );
    }

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> s = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 };

    for ( const auto &value : s )
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &value : update( s, 4 ) )
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 10 100 1000 10000 
1 4 10 40 100 400 1000 4000 10000 40000
```

According to the C++ 20 Standard (22.2.6 Associative containers)

> 9 The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of
>   iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall
>   invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

Or a more general approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

std::set<int> & update( std::set<int> &s, int value )
{
    auto partition = s.lower_bound( 0 );

    for ( auto it = rbegin( s ); it != std::set<int>::reverse_iterator( partition ); ++it )
    {
        s.insert( *it * value );
    }

    for ( auto it  = begin( s ); it != partition; ++it )
    {
        s.insert( *it * value );
    }


    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> s = { -10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 };

    for ( const auto &value : s )
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &value : update( s, 4 ) )
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-10000 -1000 -100 -10 -1 1 10 100 1000 10000 
-40000 -10000 -4000 -1000 -400 -100 -40 -10 -4 -1 1 4 10 40 100 400 1000 4000 10000 40000
```

Comment: eerorika's answer correctly handles negative number too.

Comment: @Jarod42 Except negative numbers in the original set. It's may be possible to handle them too, but it doesn't seem to be simple.

Comment: @Jarod42 actually, order of iteration doesn't even matter if set is positive and x is negative, since all elements are inserted before iterated range, so my approach is pointless.